# Select filter with JQuery mobile doesn't work

Tags: jquery, ios, jquery-mobile, cordova

I implemented a select with the code as it is on the following URL (under the option Filter Select)

http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.0/filterable/#&ui-state=dialog

For selects with a filter field, when I tried it on browsers it works fine, however when I test this on iPad or Iphone, this functionality is not working, even I tried opening the simulator from Xcode and it is still not working.

Has anyone seen this behavior?

Thanks in advance

Code looks like this

```
<form>
    <div class="ui-input-search ui-body-inherit ui-corner-all ui-shadow-inset ui-input-has-clear">
        <input data-type="search" data-enhanced="true" data-inset="false" id="pre-rendered-example-input" placeholder="Filter items..." value="au">
    </div>
    <div data-role="controlgroup" data-enhanced="true" data-filter="true" data-filter-reveal="true" data-input="#pre-rendered-example-input" class="ui-controlgroup ui-controlgroup-vertical ui-corner-all">
        <div class="ui-controlgroup-controls">
            <a href="#" class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-shadow ui-shadow ui-screen-hidden">Acura</a>
            <a href="#" class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-shadow ui-first-child ui-shadow ui-last-child">Renault</a>
            <a href="#" class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-shadow ui-shadow ui-screen-hidden">Hyundai</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

This is working on the browser but not in the device

Comment: Show us the code in the question instead....

Comment: For instance the code added above